# Which preposition does one use to specify the price of something after verbs "ankaufen" and "verkaufen"?

Tags: grammar, translation, preposition

If I want to say the price of something I sold or I bought, e.g.:

> Ich kaufte das Kleid mit zwanzig Euro an.
>   Ich verkaufte das Kleid mit dreizehn Euro.

Is "mit" the correspondent preposition to use in such case with these two verbs?

Comment: Btw, „ankaufen“ is used in trade contexts, for ordinary personal shopping we use „kaufen“.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz thx for advice

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for "**für**" (I bought the dress *in exchange* **for** 20€).

> Ich kaufte das Kleid für zwanzig Euro [an].
>
> Ich verkaufte das Kleid für dreizehn Euro.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with the existent answer, but partially. Actually that is region dependent. To be fair with [Austria and Switzerland](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f11a/)

> Ich habe dieses Buch **{für · um}** 20 Euro gekauft.

depending where you are. Same case for *verkaufen*. [image]

Comment: +1 didn't know that! Would you me tell the source for such information/charts?

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus sure, the answer has actually the link to  to the "Atlas  zur  deutschen  Alltagssprache".

Comment: So in almost Germany, they ask "wofür hast du das Buch gekauft"?!!

Comment: @Khaled I'd say rather "Wieviel hast du für *x* bezahlt?" or, if you want to use a preposition, "für welchen Preis hast du *x* gekauft?"

Comment: what about "I don't sell this picture in Gold"?!! it takes the same preposition, e.g. "Ich verkaufe das Bild für Geld nicht" is it true?!!

Comment: @Khaled if I understand correctly, *um keinen Preis der Welt verkaufe ich dieses Bild* (curiously enough, there *um* and not *für* is used).

Comment: Actually, I'd prefer „Zu welchem Preis...“.